# Why I cannot borrow something I borrowed and why I can move a method's self?

Tags: rust

I'm struggling with this simple example:

```
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};

pub struct C {
    should_continue: AtomicBool
}

impl C {
    fn a(self) -> bool{
        self.should_continue.into_inner()
    }
    // fails
    fn b(&self) -> bool{
        self.should_continue.into_inner()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let c = C {
        should_continue: AtomicBool::new(false),
    };
}
```

I think that the methods above are translated to this pseudo language:

```
fn a(c: C) -> bool {
    // ...
}

fn b(c: &C) -> bool {
    // ...
}
```

So `c.a()` should be `a(c)` and `c.b()` should be `b(&c)`. I think that in Rust, `c.a()` or `a(c)` is simply moving. And `c.b()` or `b(&c)` is borrowing.

I think that the error in `fn b(&self) -> bool` is because I'm trying to borrow to someone something that I borrowed for myself. I don't see a problem here because I can wait for `self.should_continue.into_inner()` to use the borrowed value so I can return the borrowed value. Why exactly I can't borrow something I borrowed?

Now, for `fn a(self) -> bool` it makes some sense to not give an error because it moved the value, so I can borrow it myself. However, how can I move `self`? Moving is something that does not return the object. I'm moving the object to the inside of this function, it should not exist elsewhere anymore.

Comment: `fn x(self)` effectively *consumes* `self` if you want to think of it that way. Many functions are set this way deliberately to prevent using `self` after that function is called, the object has been damaged or rendered unusable somehow.

Comment: @tadman hmmm right, just tested here. So I'm right, `fn a(self)` makes the object unusable. But why I cannot borrow something I borrowed?

Comment: You can borrow a borrow, but if you don't stop using that borrow before returning you'll end up with lifetime implications. I think the real problem here was `into_inner` takes possession, which contradicts your intentions of simply borrowing. The borrow checker is flagging this as a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't see a problem here because I can wait for `self.should_continue.into_inner()` to use the borrowed value so I can return the borrowed value. Why exactly I can't borrow something I borrowed?

That's not whats happening. Looking at the docs for [`into_inner()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicBool.html#method.into_inner), it takes a `self` parameter meaning it moves the `AtomicBool`. However, you cannot move `should_continue` from a shared reference `&C` because it would leave it in an invalid state.

> However, how can I move self? Moving is something that does not return the object. I'm moving the object to the inside of this function, it should not exist elsewhere anymore.

Think of moving in terms of ownership. Calling `c.a()` is transferring ownership of the value from the variable `c` to the parameter `self`. The value still exists, just with a new name.